# get string using stream api

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have following code :

```
private String categoryId;
List<Category> categories = new List<>();
for(String category:categories){
    if(category.getName().equals(categoryName)){
        categoryId = category.getId();
        break;
    }
}
```

I want to use stream api here to get categoryId. My category class as follows.

```
class Category{ 

  private String name;
  private String id;
  // gettters and setters.

}
```

category Id is assigned randomly when a new category is created.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. Try and provide us your actual code, and we'll be able to help you based on what you've tried

Comment: `categoryId = categories.stream()
            .filter(category -> category.getName().equals(categoryName))
            .map(Category::getCatId)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);`

Comment: @YCF_L can you change your map function. it is not working in my pc. please make it simpler

Comment: @Krissh did you mean `.map(category -> category.getCatId())`

Comment: Is Op is looking for the first category name match? I think in the above code OP is not returning on the first match. If that is the case after map it need to be reduce.
`categories.stream() .filter(category -> category.getName().equals(categoryName)).map(Category::getId).reduce((first, second) -> second).get();`

Comment: @YCF_L yes i changed it just accept

Comment: @mallikarjun I think the OP miss to use `break;` after `categoryId = category.getId();` for you @Krssh can you clarify please!

Comment: @mallikarjun yes I forgot to use break

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use this :

```
categoryId = categories.stream()
        .filter(category -> category.getName().equals(categoryName))//filter by name
        .map(Category::getId)  //get only the ids
        .findFirst()              //return just the first result
        .orElse(null);            //if no result then return null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Streams, you can write:

```
categories.stream().filter(c -> {
       if (c.getName().equals(categoryName)) categoryId = c.getId()});
```